# Expectation of integral of log ito process

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $dX_t = \mu_t^Xdt + \sigma_t^X dZ_t$. Compute the quantity $E_0[\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\rho t} log X_t dt]$.

Here's what I have so far.

$log X_t = log X_0 + \int_0^{t} dlog X_s ds$. Also, by Ito's lemma
$dlog X_t = (\mu_t^X -0.5(\sigma_t^X)^2)dt + \sigma_t^XdZ_t$. By plugging it into the expectation, I have the following
$E_0[\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\rho t} log X_t dt] = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} log X_0 dt + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} E_0\{\int_0^{t} (\mu_s^X -0.5(\sigma_s^X)^2)ds]dt\}$
This further reduces to
$E_0[\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\rho t} log X_t dt] = \frac{1}{\rho} log X_0 + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} E_0\{\int_0^{t} (\mu_s^X -0.5(\sigma_s^X)^2)ds]dt\}$.

It is not clear how to handle the second term in the R.H.S. Is the following correct?
$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} E_0\{\int_0^{t} (\mu_s^X -0.5(\sigma_s^X)^2)ds]dt\} = \frac{1}{\rho}\int_0^{\infty} E_0\{\int_0^{t} (\mu_s^X -0.5(\sigma_s^X)^2)ds]\}$

If yes, then how to reduce it further? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: What are $Z_t, \mu_t^X,$ and $\sigma_t^X$?  I think there might be some mistakes in your expression for $d\log X_t$ as well.